# Single word indexing technique

Tags: database, indexing, theory

Suppose i have a large array where each element is one word, and i want to build an index.

Take the word `Water`, i can write a function that returns

```
w
wa
wat
wate
water
at
ate
ater
ter
er
r
```

and those results would be keys in a hash table where the values are arrays of words that contain the key.

Given that i don't care about memory consumption, and the data is read only, i.e inserted only at app startup:

- theoretically what would beat this technique in terms of lookup performance?
- what the name of this technique?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie):

> a trie, also called digital tree and sometimes radix tree or prefix
>   tree (as they can be searched by prefixes), is a kind of search
>   tree—an ordered tree data structure that is used to store a dynamic
>   set or associative array where the keys are usually strings.